# How to remove li class="divider" from the last index?

Tags: php, html

I have a website where the navbar is fully dynamic, in which you can add multiple children as you want! The logic is fine, but I just need to add a divider to separate them from each other according to design requirements. Now the thing is.... The `<li class="divider"></li>` works but it also adds the divider to the last index of every iteration of navbar menu as it is self explanatory. I don't want to add a divider to the last iteration of loop!

Here's my code:

```
 <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
   <li><a href="index.php" style="color: white;"><img id="navbar-home" src="images/navbar_home.png" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
   <?php
     function display_children($parent, $level) {
       $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("not connected");
       mysqli_select_db($conn,"occ")or die ("not selected");
       $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT a.id, a.title,a.page_id, Deriv1.Count FROM `menu` a  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `menu` GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.id = Deriv1.parent WHERE a.parent=" . $parent);

       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         if ($row['Count'] > 0) {
           echo "<li><a href='" . base_url().'pages/'.$row['page_id'] . "'>" . strtoupper(str_replace('-', ' ', clean($row['title']) )). "<span class=caret></span></a>";
           echo "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">";
           display_children($row['id'], $level + 1);

           echo "</ul>";
           echo "</li>";
           echo "<li class=\"divider\"></li>";
         } elseif ($row['Count']==0) {
           echo "<li><a href='" . base_url().'pages/'.$row['page_id'] . "'>" . strtoupper(str_replace('-', ' ', clean($row['title'])) ) . "</a></li>";
           echo "<li class=\"divider\"></li>";
         } else;

       }

     }

     function clean($string) {
       return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $string); // Removes special chars.
     }

     display_children(0, 1);
   ?>
 </ul>
```

Here is the screenshot of the issue, in case someone wants clarification:

[image: The issue]

Comment: Instead of adding PHP code you can remove the bottom border using CSS `last-child`.

Comment: nice logic! demo code?

Comment: Could you add the output HTML?

Comment: Sure can you please add CSS which you have used for menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pure CSS to do this, with the [last-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) selector:

```
.nav .dropdown-menu .divider:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

To do it with php, you could instead of echoing all the menu items, add it to an array, and check if the last item is equal to the divider. Then your code would look something like this:

```
function display_children($parent, $level) {
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("not connected");
    mysqli_select_db($conn,"occ")or die ("not selected");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT a.id, a.title,a.page_id, Deriv1.Count FROM `menu` a  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `menu` GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.id = Deriv1.parent WHERE a.parent=" . $parent);

    $returnHtml = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($row['Count'] > 0) {
            $returnHtml[] = "<li><a href='" . base_url().'pages/'.$row['page_id'] . "'>" . strtoupper(str_replace('-', ' ', clean($row['title']) )). "<span class=caret></span></a>";
            $returnHtml[] = "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">";

            display_children($row['id'], $level + 1);

            $returnHtml[] = "</ul>";
            $returnHtml[] = "</li>";
            $returnHtml[] = "<li class=\"divider\"></li>";
        } elseif ($row['Count']==0) {
            $returnHtml[] = "<li><a href='" . base_url().'pages/'.$row['page_id'] . "'>" . strtoupper(str_replace('-', ' ', clean($row['title'])) ) . "</a></li>";
            $returnHtml[] = "<li class=\"divider\"></li>";
        } else;
    }

    if (end($returnHtml === "<li class=\"divider\"></li>")) {
        array_pop($returnHtml);
    }

    return implode('', $returnHtml);
}

function clean($string) {
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $string); // Removes special chars.
}

echo display_children(0, 1);
```

Comment: flawless! i was so messed up the backend, i didnt thought there could be a solution with the front end! thanks man,keep up the good work!...:)

Comment: @uneebmeer Thanks! I also added a PHP solution, if that's more your thing! If this answer helped you fix your problem, please mark it as accepted answer!